# I'm trying to use dictionary as an underlying data structure to create a simple file system. But I'm running into issues with accessing keys

Tags: python

The main idea is that when we make a directory and we call ls on a directory it should return whatever it's in b. However, I'm running into the issue that my code goes into the if statement meaning it knows there is a key in the defaultdict that matches our key(b) but it still returns None.

I'm not sure why and I would appreciate it if anyone can tell me what is wrong with my code.
Here is the command I ran:

```
fileSystem = FileSystem()
fileSystem.mkdir("/a/b/c")
fileSystem.ls("/a/b");
```

This should output ['c'] but rather my code is returning None

```
from collections import defaultdict
class FileSystem(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_system = defaultdict(list)
        self.saveData = dict()
        self.currentPath = []
    def ls(self, path):
        split_path = path.split('/')
        dest = split_path[-1]
        if dest in self.file_system.keys():
            return self.file_system.get(dest).sort()
        else:
            return self.currentPath
            
                
    
    def mkdir(self, path):
        split_path = path.split('/')
        parent = split_path[1]
        self.file_system[split_path[1]].append(split_path[1])
        self.currentPath.append(split_path[1])
        for folder in split_path[2:]:
            self.file_system[parent].append(folder)
            self.saveData[folder] = None
            parent = folder
    
    def addContentToFile(self, filePath, content):
        split_path = filePath.split('/')
        dest = split_path[-1]
        if dest in self.saveData.keys():
            history = self.saveData[dest]
            self.saveData[dest] = history + content
        else:
            self.saveData[dest] = content
    
    def readContentFromFile(self, filePath):
        split_path = filePath.split('/')
        dest = split_path[-1]
        if dest in self.saveData:
            return self.saveData[dest]
            
fileSystem = FileSystem()
fileSystem.mkdir("/a/b/c")
fileSystem.ls("/a/b");
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: It is in the bottom of the code if you could look.

Comment: I have ran my code and debugged it. The issue is what I said in my post

Comment: The issue with your post is what I described and linked to in my comments.  Please don't ping for attention until you've upgraded your post to the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: I just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

In your `ls` method you have `return self.file_system.get(dest).sort()`. The `sort` method alters the existing list and returns `None`. You need

```
return sorted(self.file_system.get(dest))
```

Since you don't provide a default value for `get` this can be written with a simple dictionary access like

```
return sorted(self.file_system[dest])
```